# Trouble using multiprocessing, a generator function and scraping urls

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to scrape a bunch of urls quickly using multiprocessing but the results do not seem to uploading to my database. Here is my code:

```py
def parse(url):
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
    MongoDBCollection.insert_one(soup)

def gen_func():
    for document in otherMongoDBCollection:
        yield document['URL']

def main():
    pool = Pool(64)
    pool.imap_unordered(parse, gen_func())
    pool.terminate()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":  # Required logic expression
    main()
```

Comment: Do you have a serial case working?

Comment: I changed `imap_unordered` to `map` and it seems to have solved my issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Pool.imap_unoredred` method returns immediately, not only after the work is done. Its return value is an iterator (thus the "i" prefix), and you're expected to iterate over all the return values to know the whole lot has been processed. If you want to wait for all the work to be completed before the main process keeps going, you probably want to use the `map` method instead (as you mention having found in a comment).

Alternatively, you could replace the call to `terminate()` with a call `close()`. That won't cut the pool's work short (just prevent any new jobs being submitted). The `join()` call will then block until the workers have all finshed.